# Eclipse Plugins: Encoding in Labels

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, swt

How do I configure the encoding of SWT-Labels in an EclipsePlugin?

I have an EclipsePlugin that makes use of an `IWorkbenchPreferencePage` under window -> preferences. The description (`setDescription()`) contains german Umlaute (ä, ö, ü) which are broken at runtime.

Additionally I have another Dialog in my plugin that shows the same issue in `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label`s. I assume that `IWorkbenchPreferencePage.setDescription()`also creates a Label, so I believe that this is the same problem.

"broken" means, that at runtime the Umlauts are displayed in two characters instead of one, I think this is because Umlauts are expressed in 2 Bytes but they are read as 1 Byte Characters.

Strangely this behavior only applys in an exported and installed Plugin, not in a Plugin that runs in a runtime-workspace (Plugin.xml -> run as Eclipse Application)

There are already some older descriptions of this Problem, suggesting to use other Fonts, but I don't believe that this is the issue.
Since the use of unicode escape characters (like \u00f6 instead "ö") in Strings yield into correct umlauts, I believe that the issue lies rather in the export process than in the Labels itself.

A short example:

Plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages">
      <page
            class="org.example.PreferencePage"
            id="org.example.PreferencePage"
            name="Umlaute">
      </page>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Implementation:

```
package org.example;

import org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditorPreferencePage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPreferencePage;

public class PreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

    @Override
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
        setDescription("This character is broken: \"ö\". This is ok: \u00f6");

    }

    @Override
    protected void createFieldEditors() {

    }

}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: WrongEncoding]

Comment: There is no 'encoding'  for labels, they are always Unicode. Show us a [mcve]

Comment: I've updated the question with an example

Comment: Works fine for me. What is the encoding you are using for the Java source file (PreferencePage.java)?

Comment: UTF-8 set in Project specific Settings. I tested this on two different Notebooks and both show the same behavior. Maybe this is related to localization of Windows...

Comment: Check the setting for the actual file (right click on the file, select Properties and look at 'Text file encoding' on the Resources tab).

Comment: It says "Other: UTF-8"

Comment: Which character is in the description at runtime, like when you look at the actual string in the debugger? Which font is being used in the screenshot, and does it support that character correctly?